# C# [x-y] range in reverse order

Tags: c#, regex

I dont know what just happened, i am using regex to extract few hidden feild value from html doc but i am getting  [x-y] range in reverse order, though i am not using any '-' in my regex expression.

html doc : https://pastee.org/rr59q

Regex expression :

`var w2 = Regex.Match("lsd\" value=\"(.*?)\"", responseText).Groups[1].Value;`

error images
http://prntscr.com/6zvbse
http://prntscr.com/6zvc0k

i even tried replacing all the - with \-

```
responseText = responseText.Replace("-", "\\-");
```

regexbuddy produces perfect result http://prntscr.com/6zvcwk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are inverting `input` and `pattern`:

```
var w2 = Regex.Match(responseText, "lsd\" value=\"(.*?)\"").Groups[1].Value;
```

First `input`, second `pattern`!

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz.aspx:

```
public static Match Match(
    string input,
    string pattern
)
```